# Cannot write to a physical disk in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows, hard-drive

I try to use Visual C++ 2008 to write a small code which will write some data to a physical disk, as follows:

```
CFile File;
CFileException FileException;
DWORD dwBytesReturned;
CByteArray Buf;

if (File.Open(_T("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1"), CFile::modeWrite | CFile::shareDenyNone | CFile::typeBinary, &FileException))
{
    if (::DeviceIoControl(File.m_hFile, FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &dwBytesReturned, NULL))
    {
        Buf.SetSize(512 * 1024);
        ::memset(Buf.GetData(), 0, Buf.GetSize());
        File.Write(Buf.GetData(), Buf.GetSize());
    }

    File.Close();
}
```

The file is opened successfully and invoke to `::DeviceIoControl` also succeeds. However, when invoking the following codeline:

```
File.Write(Buf.GetData(), Buf.GetSize());
```

I will get an exception which says

> "Access to \\.\PhysicalDrive1 was denied".

Why?

Note:

1. The first disk containing the operating system. I try to write into the second hard disk in the system.
2. When writing to the second disk, there are no other processes trying to access the data on the disk.
3. I have elevated the application to *"Administrator Privileges"*.

Thanks

Comment: "\\?\PhysicalDrive1" is a disk device. Thus its volume parameter block (VPB) is set to the RAW file system device. It's good that we have a file system, since this is a file system control, in case you didn't notice `FSCTL_` in the name.  But locking this raw file system has no bearing on whatever real file system is associated with volume devices on this disk. We're not allowed to write to sectors of a disk that are in a mounted and unlocked file system. We have to either lock or dismount the affected volume(s).

Comment: @eryksun, I lock the volume via calling ::DeviceIoControl with parameter FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME and the function returns TRUE indicates the volume is locked successfully.

Comment: You locked the RAW file system for the whole disk, which isn't necessary. You need to find, open, and lock/dismount the affected volume(s) on the disk. Enumerate volumes via `FindFirstVolumeW` / `FindNextVolumeW`. Open a handle and get its disk extents via `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS`. If an extent of the volume overlaps a byte range of the disk that you need to modify, then you'll need to lock or dismount it to get access.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you very much. I will try your method tomorrow.

Comment: @eryksun, Just let you know that your solution works perfectly. Thank you very much for your helps.